# How to add a comment liking system in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm attempting to allow a user to like comments of a particular post. However when I attempt to solve this, the expected result doesn't occur.

**urls.py:**

```
path('likecomment/<int:pk>/', post_views.likecomment, 
name='likecomment'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def likecomment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
        comment.likes += 1
        comment.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

**comments.html:**

```
{% for com in comments %}
<br>
<br>
<br>
<b>{{ com.user.username }}</b> &nbsp {{ com.body }}
<br>
<p class="text-muted">{{ com.pub_date_pretty }} &nbsp   &nbsp   
&nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  {{ com.likes }} Likes</p>
<a href="javascript: 
{document.getElementById('likecomment').submit()}"> Like </a>
<form id="likecomment" method="post" action="{% url 'likecomment' 
com.id %}">
{% csrf_token%}
<input type="hidden">
</form>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Home view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Render comments:

```
def comment(request, pk):
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post__pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment()
            comment.body =  form.cleaned_data['body']
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            comment.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'error': 'Please submit valid data'})

    else:
        return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'form': form, 'comments': comments})
```

Like comments view:

```
def likecomment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
        comment.likes += 1
        comment.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

The like occurs sometimes, however not for the right comment. The functionality isn't working correctly.

Image 1:
[image: Image1]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: Do you have Jquery loading on your document ?

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple HTML `form` elements with the same `id` (`likecomment`). Javascript has no way of knowing which one you meant to submit. Try appending a unique identifier, such as `{{ forloop.counter }}` to the `id` value, such as:

```
<form id="likecomment-{{ forloop.counter }}" ...
```

and

```
document.getElementById('likecomment-{{ forloop.counter }}').submit()
```

Comment: Hey, I have added unique id's , yet unknown behaviour occurs. I like a comment on a post, then another on the same post, and the like counter keeps going up and down. Look at my new version of the post where you can see two screenshots showing this(on the same post)

Comment: The like counter for the comments keeps changing inaccurately when I like one of the comments on the post.

Comment: I think it works fine but you think that it does not because the order of the comments change every time you load the page (the one with 2 comments goes to top when you reload). How does your `home` view look like? Are you sorting the comments in any way? Also try having different text in `com.body` as having `ss` in both will make it harder to debug.

Comment: I am not sorting comments in home.html, I am only rendering posts . However I believe the functionality is the problem, as I added two comments with unique names and half the time when I click like button, nothing happens.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Use the Network tab of your browser's inspector and see what is POST'ed to the server.

Comment: I have and the comments get sent successfully. Look at the original post, I added two photos(Taken in order). In the first one, the second comment has 2 likes. And in the second one, the same comment has 1 like. I haven't added a unliking functionality, therefore this is impossible. This shows the functionality issue I am having.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the view that renders comments.

Comment: Sure, check the original post, I have added the comment render there.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the order of the comments? Try `Comment.objects.filter(post__pk=pk).order_by("id")`.

Comment: I have added that line in, and still the same issue occurs as shown in the images within the original post.

Comment: Can you update the images with unique comment bodies please?

Comment: I have done it. On image 2, I clicked like comment on the comment named test2, however the like went to test1 instead.

Comment: This clearly shows functionality issues within the website.

Comment: Ok, now view the HTML source on the browser. Can you confirm that each Like button submits the correct form, i.e. the `likecomment-XXX` arguments match?

Comment: Yes they do. It's just the counter is inaccurate. I like one comment the other comment sometimes gains a like, and sometimes loose one